# upper limit with `PlotStyle` in `GeoListPlot` in v10.1

Tags: bugs, geography

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2**

---

Let's start with the code below:

```
xx = 21;
GeoListPlot[List /@ GeoPosition /@ RandomReal[50, {xx, 2}], 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[Directive[ColorData[97, i]], {i, xx}]]
```

After run it, error messages like

```
Part::partw: Part 21 of{{,EdgeForm[{Thickness[Tiny],Opacity[0.4]}],PointSize[Large],FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5    ]}]},<<18>>,{,EdgeForm[{Thickness[Tiny],Opacity[0.4]}],PointSize[Large],FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5]}]}} does not exist. >>
```

will show up.

However, once `xx` is decreased to a number less than 21, say 20 or 15 or whatever, the code above will run as normal.

So, **is there a bug in the limit of `PlotStyle`'s you can specify?**

Comment: Please do not use the 'bugs' tag for behaviour that is not confirmed by members of the community or WRI developers as a bug. This is mentioned in the tag wiki.

Comment: ColorData[97] is probably finite and less than 21 long. There are a few infinite ColorData sets, but most are finite. You can find information about the various colour sets in the color palette.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks for the correction in the tag use. I checked that `ColorData[97]` is infinite.

Comment: Yep, its a bug that slipped through. Other than the message, it works fine. For instance, try `ConstantArray[Red, 20]~Join~{Blue}` as your `PlotStyle` and you'll see all the points are colored correctly.

Comment: In that case an Off[Part::partw] before and an On[Part::partw] after the GeoListPlot might be added to get rid of the erroneaous message for now.

Comment: @rcollyer, I noticed that the code works fine. One thing annoying is the red alert frame over the output, in particular if `Frame->True`, which thus inhibits  the exported file as an acceptable artwork.

Comment: the OFF-ON procedure doesn't help much: the red frame persists.

Comment: Had a possible workaround, but it doesn't work. So, I deleted it.

Comment: Got it working. Enjoy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a workaround.

```
Off[Part::partw]
GeoListPlot[ ... ] /. Verbatim[Part][___] :> {}
On[Part::partw]
```

which strips out the part that is causing the pink boxes. I don't recall what `"OriginalInput"` is involved in, so strip it out if you absolutely have to.

---

**Fixed in 10.2**

[image]

Comment: brilliant! thanks! also hope this can be soon fixed ;)

Comment: It is fixed, just not in the most recent release ...